AndroidStudio - App Link Verification is failing even when the assetlinks.json is present
As per the documentation we have published the assetlinks.json into our server at app-deeplink.domain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json. But when verifying the same with App Link Assistant in Android Studio, it specifies that the assetlinks.json doesn't exist in the respective path.
The following checks are also verified from the server side as per the doc

The assetlinks.json file is served with content-type application/json.
The assetlinks.json file must be accessible over an HTTPS connection, regardless of whether your app's intent filters declare HTTPS as the data scheme.
The assetlinks.json file must be accessible without any redirects (no 301 or 302 redirects).

When verifying the same with App Link Assistant in Android Studio, it specifies that the assetlinks.json doesn't exist in the respective path.
App Link Assistant (App link details window)

App Link Assitant (Declaring website association window)

While verifying the same with Statement List Tester we are getting the following error in response
********************* ERRORS *********************
* Error: unavailable: 
Error fetching statements from https://app-deeplink.*.com./.well-known/assetlinks.json (which is equivalent to 'https://app-deeplink.*.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json'): 
URL_ERROR/3 [4] while fetching Web statements from https://app-deeplink.*.com./.well-known/assetlinks.json (which is equivalent to 'https://app-deeplink.*.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json') using download from the web (ID 1).


Note: Domain has been redacted, but it'll be like app-deeplink.*.com

Check access.log of the web server providing your domain. You should find tries to access assetlinks.json from IPs that belong to Google. What happens if you try to access the assetlinks.json file from a smartphone using cellular network without any VPN or proxy and the smartphone has no additional root CA certificates installed?
